# Calculating a Square around a Geoposition

Tags: geometry

We need to find points of interest near a user's location (50km)
We have a way to calculate if the point of interest is within a circle around him, but theses calculations are too heavy for our servers.

By first finding the POI's inside of a square around the user, it would solve the problem.

Data :
user.latitude, user.longitude
list of POI's: poi.latitude, poi.longitude

We need to find the maxLatitude (+50km); the minLatitude (-50km); minLongitude and maxLongitude to have the square.

EDIT: I thought these calculations were incorrect but they are in fact precise enough for us and used for France.

```
minLatitude = latitude - R * 0.009
maxLatitude = latitude + R * 0.009
minLongitude = longitude - R * 0.0143
maxLongitude = longitude + R * 0.0143
```

Comment: There is no linear correction for the earth's curvature.  You will likely need to find some simple approximation that gets you "close enough".

Comment: Do you know if the user has some constraints on their position, in particular latitude?

Comment: it's limited to France; just found out our problem came from outside these formulaes. It works

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless you are within 50 km of a pole, your square around (lon $\alpha$, lat $\beta$) should extend to approximately $\beta\pm \frac{50}{111}$ degrees (because one degree is roughly 111 km) in latitude, and to approximately $\alpha \pm\frac{50}{111\cos \beta}$ in longitude. (It appears that you arriverd at *your* formulas by considering a place at about $50^\circ $ N or S).

Comment: yes I'm French (48° lat) you are right :)

Answer (score 1):

If you are sufficiently far away from a pole, you can use a linear approximation. To do this you need to figure out the rate of change of position with respect to latitude, longitude.

If the latitude, longitude are given by $\theta, \phi$  radians and the Earth's radius is $R$, then the $(x,y,z)$ coordinates are given by
$p(\theta, \phi) = R(\cos \phi \cos \theta, \cos \phi \sin \theta, \sin \phi)$.

Then, if you work through the calculus, you get
$\|{\partial p(\theta, \phi) \over \partial \phi} \| = R$,
$\|{\partial p(\theta, \phi) \over \partial \theta} \| = R|\cos \phi|$ (the
longitude is always in $[-{ \pi \over 2} , {\pi \over 2}]$, so we can drop the absolute value).

Hence for a small change in latitude $\delta_\theta$, we have
$\|p(\theta+\delta_\theta, \phi) - p(\theta,\phi) \| \approx \|{\partial p(\theta, \phi) \over \partial \theta} \delta_\theta\| = (R \cos \phi ) |\delta_\theta|$, and similarly for a small change in
longitude $\delta_\phi$, 
$\|p(\theta, \phi+\delta_\phi) - p(\theta,\phi) \| \approx \|{\partial p(\theta, \phi) \over \partial \phi} \delta_\phi\| = R |\delta_\phi|$.

To find the approximate changes **in radians** that result in a point a distance $L$ away,
we solve  $(R \cos \phi ) |\delta_\theta| \le L$, $R |\delta_\phi| \le L$ to get
$|\delta_\theta| \le {L \over R \cos \phi}, |\delta_\phi| \le {L \over R}$.

**Addendum**: If you would rather a circle, and squaring is not too much of a load, you can follow the above procedure to get a reasonable approximation.

We have $\|p(\theta+\delta_\theta, \phi+\delta_\phi) - p(\theta,\phi) \| \approx \|Dp((\theta,\phi))((\delta_\theta, \delta_\phi)) \|$, where
$Dp((\theta,\phi))((\delta_\theta, \delta_\phi))$ is the derivative of $p$ at the point $(\theta,\phi)$ in the direction $(\delta_\theta, \delta_\phi)$.

We can grind through the calculus to get
$\|Dp((\theta,\phi))((\delta_\theta, \delta_\phi)) \| = R\sqrt{(\cos^2 \phi )\delta_\theta^2 + \delta_\phi^2}$.

Hence, as before, we want to solve $\|Dp((\theta,\phi))((\delta_\theta, \delta_\phi)) \| \le L$, which gives
$(\cos^2 \phi )\delta_\theta^2 + \delta_\phi^2 \le {L \over R}$.
(Again, keep in mind that the angles above are in radians.)